# Enable client side validation on disabled select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-3.1

I got a project using asp.net core 3.1 MVC.
It contains a form with a selection that is disabled.

```
    <div class="col-12 mb-3">
        <select asp-for="SelectableItem" class="multi-select form-control" id="selectedItem" disabled="disabled" required="required">
            <option value="">-- Select Item --</option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="SelectableItems" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

The fully rendered html

```
<select class="multi-select form-control" id="selectedItem" disabled="" required="required" 
    data-val="true" data-val-required="Selected Item is required" 
    name="SelectedItem">          
     <option value="">-- Select Item --</option>
</select>
```

This selection is disabled until the user checks a box, which then populates the select element and enables it, as the content depens on wat checkbox has been selected.

When the user tries to submit the form the validation of JQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive validates everything except that disabled field, as the field is required however i would like for it to be validated as well.

I only want it to be enabled for that one form, so not all disabled elements throughout the application, but can't seem to get it to work.

I tried the following and some variants of it.

```
$('form').validator.setDefaults({ignore: null})

$('form').data('validator').settings.ignore = "";

$('form').validator.setDefaults({ignore: []})

$('#selectableItem').Validate().settings.not('[disabled]')
```

Non of these seem to do anything, the disabled select refuses to get validated, and all other suggestions like readonly doesn't work on select elements, nor do i want it to be globally allowed, as that would mess up some other forms.

Comment: I did update the sample quickly, but no it doesn;t contain a name, and yes i use the standart submit, Alhough after i enable it the validation works just fine? so the name doesn't seem to impact that?

Comment: Fair enough! assumingi add a name, does that change anything? I added one manually now, just to be save, but that also doesn't make it validate either.

Comment: Haha, all good, also i can tell you after inspecting the code that yes, a name gets added that equals that of the bound model property.

Comment: If the field is `disabled` via the `disabled` attribute, the jQuery Validate plugin will always ignore it.But if you change to `readonly`,it could work well in my project,it validates the selectlist field.Dot sure why did you does not work,maybe you need provide more code for your js and what js plugin did you reference in your project?

Comment: Making the select shown in my sampl code readonly does not prevent anyone from using it, only from selecting different options, if they then select this list they see it's empty, which might cause confusion, especially if it throws warnings about it as well.

Comment: Hi @Black Lotus,Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to validate all disabled form fields, the relevant line in the plugin is:

```
.not( ":submit, :reset, :image, :disabled" )
```

Follow the steps:

1.Find the `jquery.validate.js` in your project.

[image]

2.Open the js and press `ctrl` + `F` to find the line contains `disabled`,them comment on this line(or you could remove the `:disabled` in this line):

[image]

3.If you use the default asp.net core project,remember to change the `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml`.Because this view add a reference for `jquery.validate.min.js`,but you modify the `jquery.validate.js`(If you still want to use min.js,please read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and learn how to bundle and minify static assets ):

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script> //change here...
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a working demo:

Model(add `[Required]`attribute):

```
public class Test
{
    [Required]       //add this
    public string SelectableItem { get; set; }
}
```

View(remove `required="required"`):

```
@model Test
<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div class="col-12 mb-3">
        <select asp-for="SelectableItem" class="multi-select form-control" id="selectedItem" disabled="disabled">
            <option value="">-- Select Item --</option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="SelectableItem" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>

@section Scripts
{
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input:checkbox').change(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                    //add to select list
                    $("#selectedItem").append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", "1")
                        .text("aa"));
                    $("#selectedItem").append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", "2")
                        .text("bb"));
                    $("#selectedItem").append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", "3")
                        .text("cc"));
                    // $("selectedItem").prop('required', true);
                    $("#selectedItem").removeAttr('disabled');
                }
                else {
                    //remove item from select list
                    $("#selectedItem").empty().append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", "")
                        .text("-- Select Item --"));
                    $("#selectedItem").prop('disabled', true);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Result:

[image]